# Exception: ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java

I get `array index out of bounds exception` when trying to read data from a file into an array. The file has 700 lines data similar to:

`"Vasculitis_PlasmaExchange", "#FCE883", "http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18646089", "(252, 232, 131)"`

`"Vasculitis_Prednisone", "#C5E384", "http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19588365", "(197, 227, 132)"`

my code is:

```
static{  
    COLOR_CODES = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    try{ 
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Crayon.properties");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;

        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {       

            COLOR_CODES.add(new String[]{line});               
        } 
        br.close();
        fr.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't load array file");
    }       
}

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException,
        IOException
{
    JSONArray fullColorArray;
    String query = request.getParameter("q");

    try {
        int count = 0;
        if (query.equals(m_lastQuery)) {
            fullColorArray = m_lastResults;
            count = m_lastResults.length();
        } else {
            m_lastQuery = query;

            fullColorArray = new JSONArray();
            for (String[] colorCode : COLOR_CODES) {
                String colorName = colorCode[0];
                String lowerColor = colorName.toLowerCase();
                int has = lowerColor.indexOf(query.toLowerCase());

                if (!query.isEmpty() && (query.equals("*") || has >= 0)) {
                    JSONObject color = new JSONObject();
                    color.put("DisplayName", colorName);
                    color.put("Value", colorCode[1]); // <-------- ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
                    color.put("Description", colorCode[2]);
                    color.put("RGB", colorCode[3]);
                    fullColorArray.put(color);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            m_lastResults = fullColorArray;
        }
```

NullPointerException:

### HTTP ERROR: 500

```
INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

RequestURI=/multivaluesuggestboxexample/colors

#### Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.spiffyui.spiffynavigation.server.CrayonColorsServlet.doGet(CrayonColorsServlet.java:95)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)

(Based on [CrayonColorsServlet.java](https://github.com/spiffyui/MvsbSamples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spiffyui/mvsb/samples/server/CrayonColorsServlet.java))

Please help.

AM Mohan Rao

Comment: You should add stacktrace message to your question and explain what you expect from this code, because save whole line to `new String[]{line}` have no reason.

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at org.spiffyui.spiffynavigation.server.CrayonColorsServlet.doGet(CrayonColorsServlet.java:103)
 color.put("Value", colorCode[1]);
I used MVsb sample (https://github.com/spiffyui/MvsbSamples) (integrated into "Navigation" sample) for autocomplete display of data. A .classpath has "src/main/resources" where the data file is kept. This error occurs both at cmd and eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want something like :

```
 while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)        
      COLOR_CODES.add(line.split(","));
```

Comment: Yes, but this couldn't be the case of ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: It gave NullPointerException ? I should split using ",

Comment: Add some logging where you split the line to check the result. If you split correctly and set the strings in your array this should work

Comment: @user2339074 - post the NullPointerException you have

Comment: NullPointerException is at "count = m_lastResults.length();" Please note that COLOR_CODES.add(new String[]{"Vasculitis_PlasmaExchange", "#FCE883", "http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18646089", "(252, 232, 131)"});
COLOR_CODES.add(new String[]{"Vasculitis_Prednisone", "#C5E384", "http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19588365", "(197, 227, 132)"}); works perfectly.

Comment: I found COLOR_CODES.add(line.split(",")); works. But the color codes are missing. They should have been there from "#FCE883" & (252, 232, 131) etc.

Comment: line.split(",") also breaks at "(252," and no color code is shown. similar result with line.split(", "). Both show "vasculitis.." (as in "") which should be without quotes.

Comment: Use`line.split("\", \"")` and remove the first and the last `"` with `substring`

Comment: Thanks. Problem is I can't implement code changes easily because GWT implements JASON, MVsb is not debug enabled, jetty server accessed from eclipse debug mode results are unpredictable.  I tried all options and (as I am not a software professional) I am satisfied with results so far.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify where an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception occurs - I assume that location is not in above code.

Why do you construct an ArrayList of arrays? Are you aware that the line

```
COLOR_CODES.add(new String[]{line});
```

adds an array to the ArrayList; the array itself containing one single element, that is the line that was just read.

Could it be that you wanted to do something like

```
COLOR_CODES.add(line.split('insert_your_split_regex_here'));
```

?

Comment: It is convenient to access multiple values in a autocomplete suggest box by having array of arrays. Also, split by "\"," gives error.

Comment: After your line `String[] somearray = someline.split("\\",");`, add a check like `if(somearray.length != 4) { System.err.println("Error parsing line " + someline + " , array was: " + Arrays.toString(somearray)); }`

Answer (score 1):

Split the line into `String[]` based upon your delimiter.

Comment: both "," and "\"," split end up with NullPointerExceptions while accessing the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that code could possibly give that exception.

- None of the methods or primitive operations used in that code will throw that exception
- If they (hypothetically) did, then the `catch` would turn it into a different exception and you wouldn't see any trace of the original exception in the stack trace (if any).

I think you will find that it is being thrown in some other code.  Unless include that other code and a stacktrace, I don't think we can help you.  (Better still, provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) ... so that we can reproduce the error.)

  -

Comment: The sample is available at:https://github.com/spiffyui/MvsbSamples. Line 65 generates NullPointerException at line 90 && ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at 101. Please note that I transferred data from crayoncolorservlet.java to crayon.properties file. This file is at src\main\resources which is in classpath. Hence, I am assuming the file is accessible for the array.

Comment: If I never see the catch exception does it guarantee that my file is surely read?

Comment: 1) A can't make out which file you are actually referring to.  2) Not necessarily.  There are circumstances where uncaught exceptions never get reported.

Comment: The NullPointerException I get seems to be because the Crayon.properties file is read only when it is at outermost folder and not when it is at its classpath.