# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, can't locate its origin

Tags: java

I have written a class `TokenizableString` that tokenizes a string given as input from the user. Here's an example of how it should go

I type

```
"My name is methos"
```

I should see in console the following

```
'My'
'name'
'is'
'methos'
```

There's one problem, when I enter the following input : `"Badr          "`
I receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at exercicesPOO.TokenizableString.<init>(TokenizableString.java:40)
    at exercicesPOO.TokenizableString.main(TokenizableString.java:127)
Java Result: 1
```

Whereas the desired output should be : `'Badr'`. Notice that the blank spaces at the end of the word are removed (There is a method for that in my code).

I have been looking into my code for quite some time, I still can't locate where the 'index out of bounds' error is coming from.

I have tried running the debugger, it seems it never goes beyond the constructor call for this particular input : `"Badr       "`.

Also would you be kind and give a mark to the readability/quality of my coding. Any suggestion/remarks are more than welcome.Thanks in advance.

P_S: I'm using Netbeans.

Here's the code:

```
package debugging;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TokenizableString {
        static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
        private String contenu;
        private int from;
        private int len;       

        //Constructeurs
        public TokenizableString(String contenu)
        {  
                this.contenu = contenu;
                System.out.print(this.contenu);
                System.out.println("<--- Ended here");
                this.removeExtraSpaces();
                System.out.print(this.contenu);               
                System.out.println("<--- Ended here");
                this.from=0;
                this.len = 0;
                char[] contenuChar = this.contenu.toCharArray();
                int i = 0;
                do
                {
                        this.len++;
                        i++;
                }while(i<contenuChar.length && contenuChar[i] != ' ');
                // La condition est qu'il faut calculer la longueur de la première séquence de lettres (du premier mot) en itérant soit jusqu'au prochain ' ' (espace) ou jusqu'à atteindre la fin de la phrase.
                //The condition is that we have to calculate the length of the first sequence of letters (first word) by iterating until the next ' ' (blank space) or until we reach the end of the sentence.
        }

        //Methods

        //removeExtraSpaces() removes the spaces that the user would have entered at the end of the inputed string for example : "Badr              " would become "Badr"
        private void removeExtraSpaces()
        {
                boolean Acc = true;
                do
                {
                        if(this.contenu.charAt(this.contenu.length()-1)==' ')
                        {
                                char[] temp = new char[this.contenu.length()-1];

                                for(int i = 0 ; i < this.contenu.length() -1; i++)
                                {                                        
                                        temp[i] = this.contenu.charAt(i);
                                }
                                String tempStr ="";
                                for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
                                {
                                        tempStr += temp[i];
                                }
                                this.contenu = tempStr;                    
                                if(this.contenu.charAt(this.contenu.length()-1)==' ')
                                {
                                        Acc= false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        Acc = true;
                                        break;
                                }
                        }                        
                }while(Acc == false);
        }


        //nextToken() places the 'from' in the beggining of a word and calculates the length of that given word via 'len'. If there we reach the end of the sentence this method will return false.
        public boolean nextToken()
        {                
                char[] contenuChar = this.contenu.toCharArray();

                if ( (this.from+this.len+1) < contenuChar.length && ( ( this.from == 0 && contenuChar[this.from+this.len] == ' ' ) || ( this.from !=0 && contenuChar[this.from - 1] == ' ' ) ) )
                {                   

                        this.from += (this.len +1);
                        this.len = 0;                       
                        int i = this.from;
                        while( i < contenuChar.length)
                        {
                                if(contenuChar[i] != ' ')
                                {
                                        this.len++;
                                        i++;    
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        break;
                                }
                        }                        
                        //Nous avons donné une nouvelle valeures aux variables from et len.
                        //System.out.println("from = "+this.from+" || len= "+this.len);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }

        //putting the given words of a sentence via previous method into a dynamic array.
        public void tokenize()
        {
                ArrayList <String> mots = new ArrayList<>();
                do
                {                       
                        String mot = "";
                        for(int i = from; i < (this.len+this.from); i++)
                        {
                                mot += contenu.charAt(i);
                        }
                        mots.add(mot);
                }while(this.nextToken() == true);

                for(String mot : mots)
                {
                        System.out.println("'"+mot+"'");
                }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String phrase;
                System.out.println("Entrez une chaine :");
                phrase = scanner.nextLine();
                TokenizableString toToken = new TokenizableString(phrase);
                toToken.tokenize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using .trim() to remove the spaces?

Comment: Because I'm supposed to 'comprehend and rewrite' functions like .trim() or split(). It's the point of the exercice.

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate of that pointed by Jarrod Roberson.

The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316810/exception-arrayindexoutofbounds
isn't even answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your while conditions has wrong order, first check for i being inside the range then for the space.

Comment: The && (Logical AND) is supposedly commutative.

Comment: so your contenuChar has length 3. you are at i = 3, what happens? You check that contenuChar[3] !=  ' ' and you are already otouside the table size, as the last available indes is 2. If you change the order it works. The && operation is shortcut, when first operation gives false the && results must be false so it is not evaluated and you are not chekcign content outside your table range.

Comment: I did switch them, still doesn't work.
EDIT : Wait omg, there was another one and I switched it too and it worked. THANKS

Comment: Could you please rate my code? I'd like feedback on how well I'm coding.

Comment: Is it a feature for that on stacktrace? Honestly, you need lots of work. For example your removeExtra... you keep unecessary copying table in the loop (btw there is System.arrayCopy, Arrays.copyof for that), then you make new string (again constly) just to check its last character. The whole method could be as simple as:
int lastNS = contenu.length()-1;
while (lastNS >= 0 && contenu.charAt(lastNS) == ' ') lastNS--;
contenu = contenu.substring(0,lastNS+1);

Comment: Nono it's not a feature, just give me a mark, say like... On a scale of 1 to 10 how well written/Organized/efficient is my code to you.

Thank you for the remark, I've noted it :).